# MediaElementJS setCurrentTime not working in chrome only

Tags: wordpress, html5-video, mediaelement.js

I have read lot of threads on it, but nothing seems solved my problem. I have install mediaelementjs wordpress plugin and then use [video ] shortcode on my page. I set the video to autoplay. Now we have put some Anchor on video through links when user click on those link video is support to jump to those time. for this I use following code.

```
function SwitchEncore(me,hour, minute, second) {
//make a video timeshift.
jQuery('#tabHeading ul li').removeClass('selectedTab');
jQuery(me).addClass('selectedTab');

var myplayer = jQuery("#wp_mep_1");//.mediaelementplayer();
var thisplayer = myplayer[0];
var time =  (hour*60*60 ) + (minute*60) + (second*1);

thisplayer.player.pause();
thisplayer.player.setCurrentTime(time);
thisplayer.player.play();

}
```

This code works on Firefox and IE, but not on Chrome. Any idea what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried running load() prior to play?
I have found this to fix some of the issues I have run across

Comment: well I did try load but it doesn't help me. However I found that my Server is not sending or responding to RESUME request, basically my server is not responding to PARTIAL Content [HTTP CODE 206] which is required by Chrome to start movie at given point. So, I change the server and it works fine. However i am still confuse why FF or IE doesn't need such server .. maybe they use their own resume/seek using buffered video.